# How to get my Logitech V220 mouse working?

Tags: usb, mouse, arch-linux, drivers

The only relevant information I've been able to find was this old [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=53704). My system settings:

```
╭─ting@noa ~ ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep Name
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="Integrated Camera"
N: Name="Lid Switch"
N: Name="Sleep Button"
N: Name="Power Button"
N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
N: Name="HDA Digital PCBeep"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
N: Name="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
N: Name="Video Bus"
╭─ting@noa ~ ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
╭─ting@noa ~ ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  lsmod
...
xhci_hcd               79548  0 
ehci_hcd               43944  0 
usbcore               146815  8 ehci_hcd,xhci_hcd,uvcvideo,btusb,cdc_acm,uas,usb_storage
usb_common               954  1 usbcore
╭─ting@noa ~ ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  grep modules /etc/rc.conf
# MODULES: Modules to load at boot-up. Blacklisting is no longer supported.
MODULES=(loop uvcvideo vboxdrv)
```

I'm not sure what modules I need to install and have running, and I can't find any information in the wiki.

Adding additional information:

```
╭─ting@noa ~/downloads ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  sudo pacman -Ss extra/xf86-input-evdev
Password: 
< nothing happened >
╭─ting@noa ~/downloads ‹python-2.7.3› ‹ruby-1.9.3› 
╰─➤  ls -la /dev/input/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 May  6 10:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 360 May  6 10:10 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May  6 10:10 usb-Chicony_Electronics_Co.__Ltd._Integrated_Camera-event-if00 -> ../event1
```

#### Misc

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log output](http://pastebin.com/dEnZi8Xq)

Plugging in the USB receiver:

```
[363745.733685] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[364191.257776] [drm:pch_irq_handler] *ERROR* PCH poison interrupt
[364196.510237] usb 2-1: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[364196.559283] usb 2-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[364196.559287] usb 2-1: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[364635.162505] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[367291.323611] usb 4-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[368044.221062] usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[376432.690911] [drm:pch_irq_handler] *ERROR* PCH poison interrupt
[379421.904048] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[379421.904051] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6040
[379421.904053] thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[379421.904584] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[379432.308444] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[379432.308447] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6040
[379432.308449] thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[379432.308961] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[385383.174565] usb 4-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
```

Comment: Presumably you want your mouse to work in X Server?  Can you [edit] and add the results of `pacman -Ss extra/xf86-input-evdev`, `ls -la /dev/input/by-id` and put a copy of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` into pastebin?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I've added the requested info.

Comment: What kernel do you have installed -standard arch or AUR?  Do you have udev installed?  Could you try searching pacman for just evdev?  Could you try unplugging and replugging in the mouse then check the end of `dmesg`?

Comment: Standard (3.3.4-2-ARCH), udev is installed, xf86-input-evdev is installed. I've updated the original post with `dmesg` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that ArchLinux was not loading the `usbhid` module. After loading it manually, the mouse worked fine. Since then I've added to the modules list in `/etc/rc.conf`.

While `usbhid` should be loaded automatically without needing me to add it, I don't mind as long as the mouse works.